# quot in string for htmlhelper c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any solution for this ?

This is not working

```
$("#spanfile").html(@Html.ResourceScriptString("error","please.choose.file"));
```

where

```
public static string ResourceScriptString(this HtmlHelper html, string type, string key)
{
  return HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(ResourceDBManager.CachedObject.getValue(type, key), true);
}
```

I DO want write it nicely, cause this is working but with javascript parsing error in VS

```
$("#spanfile").html("@Html.ResourceScriptString("error","please.choose.file")");
```

where

```
public static string ResourceScriptString(this HtmlHelper html, string type, string key)
{
  return HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(ResourceDBManager.CachedObject.getValue(type, key), false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work:

```
$("#spanfile").html(@Html.ResourceScriptString("error","please.choose.file"));
```

Because the result would be something like:

```
$("#spanfile").html(some value);
```

That would result in a JavaScript error.  The server-side code which emits the string emits it just as its value, not with any quotes around it.  You need to supply the quotes.  Which you do here:

```
$("#spanfile").html("@Html.ResourceScriptString("error","please.choose.file")");
```

Though this is likely confusing Visual Studio.  Luckily JavaScript allows you to specify a string with single-quotes instead, if that's better:

```
$("#spanfile").html('@Html.ResourceScriptString("error","please.choose.file")');
```

This may still confuse the intellisense in Visual Studio (it's better in 2012 at least, but I know mixing Razor and JavaScript confuses the heck out of 2010), but should physically work.